# Event listener in a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, listener

So, this is probably a very basic design question, but Im just not sure how to go about it.

Normally, when I use event listeners, I define it in whatever class, then I override the necessary methods in my Activity and instantiate the class and the listener as needed.

However, in this case, I have my MainActivity class (that also implements the listener), a class (called testClass) that implements the listener, and a broadcast receiver class. The broadcast receiver class instantiates the calls  the testClass. Now, what I am trying to do is to update a TextView in MainActivity when a given function is called in the  testClass.

Not sure how to go about this.

Hope this wobbly issue description makes sense.

Comment: Use e.g [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or a [LocalBroadcast](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/) so you the event emitter does not need to know the event receiver.

Comment: Why not use a delegate to indicate the update ?

Comment: Never heard of either. LocalBroadcast sounds especially promising! Thanks!

Comment: zapl is right. LocalBroadcast is cool thing. Personally I use this mechanism for REST client: Activity <-> LocalBroadcast <-> IntentService (interaction with server).

Comment: LocalBroadcast was simple and worked perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've tackled in the past when using a background Service to update data that is displayed on screen. The general pattern I use is to add a member variable to your processing class (in this case, I think it's your TestClass) that is a Map (named something like mCallbackMap) with android.os.Handler as the key and your listener object as the value (normally this will be an interface that you define). The Handler, which is created in the Activity and thus associated with the main thread, is needed because you can't change the UI of an Activity from outside the main Thread; you'll use the Handler to post a runnable to the main thread instead of manipulating it directly.

When your activity gets going, probably in onCreate, onStart, or onResume, you'll register it as a callback with your TestClass by using the mCallbackMap's put() method. Simply instantiate a Handler, which you'll also store as a member variable of your activity, and use it as the key and your Activity as the value. You'll need to remove the callback in onPause or onStop so you don't leak the activity after it's out of view.

Then, once TestClass finishes handling whatever the broadcast gives it, you'll iterate through your mCallbackMap (maybe you have more than one callback, maybe you don't) and call Handler.post(Runnable). In the Runnable's run() method, you call the callback's methods as appropriate.